# Amazon SES example Perl script not working in raw -r mode using stdin under windows

Tags: perl, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to get Amazon SES to work to send email using their example scripts. I'm not a Perl guy really, but the examples are in Perl, so be it.

The SES examples provide a script to verify your from: address (done that) and to check stats (works fine) and to send an email (that works too, until...)

I can send email, in simple param mode or raw param mode, if I use STDIN and type out the message body parts-- either the whole message in the case of raw or just the actual body in the case of simple. That works fine. However, if I use < to use input from a file instead, it won't read it. It says "Missing From", and then if I specify that on the command line I get "Missing To" and if I specify that as well on the command line I get "Missing Subject" -- and if you try to specify the subject on the command line together with the -r option it correctly replies that you are not allowed to specify the subject when using raw mode. (apparently you *can* specify the from and to, though.)

I've got ActiveState Perl 5.12.3 Build 1204. I've got all the prereqs installed, apparently, as I can send email just fine until I try to get it to read data from a file as STDIN. I'm running Win Srv 03 R2 SP2. I've already gotten production access from Amazon, and I'm no where near my limit of 1000 emails per day.

This is an example of the command I'm trying to run:

```
C:\amazon-testing-folder\perl>ses-send-email.pl -k aws-credentials -r < raw-email.txt
Missing Required header 'From'.
```

Using a relative or absolute path/file spec doesn't change anything. Giving an invalid file name properly causes the OS to report "The system cannot find the file specified".

Best I can tell, this line seems to read nothing if I specify a file name.

```
$opts{'m'} = join '', readline *STDIN;
```

It's in ses-send-email.pl, a few lines from the top in sub read_message{}.

I've tried putting in a few debugging lines after that to see if it is reading anything in, and they seem to confirm that it is not. My raw file is formatted properly, and yes, it has a From: line and a To: line! And a Subject: line!  I've also removed all the header lines that were not in Amazon's list of supported headers (like Content-Class: ).

Has anyone gotten this to work? Thanks in advance... Not sure what to try next.

Example raw-email.txt file:  (I also tried changing the order of the header lines, but I really don't think it is reading in the file.)

```
To: <anyone@anywhere.com>
From: <a-verified-address@domain.com>
Message-ID: <697745840.1.1292371199964@0023df9374dc>
Subject:  February 21 Test
Date: Mon, 21 Feb 2011 05:00:00 -0600
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;   
    boundary="----=abcdefg"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

If you are seeing this message, your mail program
doesn't understand rich-formatted email. 

----=abcdefg
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Text Message Goes Here.

----=abcdefg
Content-Type: text/html;
    charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

HTML<br>version<br>goes<br>here<br>

----=abcdefg--
```

Comment: Where's the Perl code? No one can say what's wrong with it if you don't show it.

Comment: I doubt there's really something wrong with the Perl-- Amazon would test this stuff right? The example scripts are at http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/Amazon-SES/8945574369528337

Comment: Direct link to zip file: http://aws-catalog-download-files.s3.amazonaws.com/AmazonSES-2011-02-02.zip

Answer (score 1):

I used the debugger and cannot reproduce your error message. The program reads from STDIN just fine, then bombs out only in `SES::call_ses` because I don't have an Amazon key.

```
$ perl -d ses-send-email.pl -k aws-credentials -r < raw-email.txt

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.33
Editor support available.

Enter h or `h h' for help, or `man perldebug' for more help.

main::(ses-send-email.pl:30):   my  %opts = ();
  DB<1> c 138
main::(ses-send-email.pl:138):  my ($response_code) = SES::call_ses \%params, \%opts;
  DB<2> xx \%params
{
  Action => "SendRawEmail",
  "RawMessage.Data" => "VG86IDxhbnlvbmVAYW55d2hlcmUuY29tPgpGcm9tOiA8YS12ZXJpZmllZC1hZGRyZXNzQGRvbWFp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\nZ29lczxicj5oZXJlPGJyPgoKLS0tLT1hYmNkZWZnLS0=\n"
}

  DB<3> xx \%opts
{
  b => undef,
  c => undef,
  e => undef,
  f => undef,
  h => undef,
  k => "aws-credentials",
  m => "To: <anyone\@anywhere.com>\nFrom: <a-verified-address\@domain.com>\nMessage-ID: <697745840.1.1292371199964\@0023df9374dc>\nSubject:  February 21 Test\nDate: Mon, 21 Feb 2011 05:00:00 -0600\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Type: multipart/alternative;\n    boundary=\"----=abcdefg\"\n\nThis is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\nIf you are seeing this message, your mail program\ndoesn't understand rich-formatted email.\n\n----=abcdefg\nContent-Type: text/plain\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\nText Message Goes Here.\n\n----=abcdefg\nContent-Type: text/html;\n    charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\n\nHTML<br>version<br>goes<br>here<br>\n\n----=abcdefg--",
  r => 1,
  s => undef,
  t => undef,
  verbose => undef
}

  DB<4>
```

Comment: Okay-- Perl -d got me heading in the right direction. It seems like my raw-email.txt is not in the right format... UTF7 vs Unicode I think? Ugh. Thanks!!!

Comment: The email as shown in the question should be saved encoded as ASCII. Creating "raw" emails correctly is troublesome, if you keep having problems, let [Email::MIME](http://p3rl.org/Email::MIME) produce them.

Answer (score 0):

For the next guy running up against this:

Firstly, make sure your input file (the file that you specify after < mark) is UFT8 w/o BOM, ASCII, ANSI. I think the key is 7 bits? Anyway, not unicode, and not UTF16. If you get Missing Required header 'From' and your file has the From: header in it, then your encoding is wrong.

Once you get that straightened out, you might get "Missing start boundary". This most likely is due to having dashes in the wrong place. When building MIME from scratch (not that you should have to... but I did...) the "boundary" that defines boundary should look more like

```
boundary="some-boundary-string"
```

and then the actual boundaries should look like

```
--some-boundary-string
```

note that the actual boundaries have two dashes, where the original definition does not. So if the definition has four dashes, the actual boundaries will need six. And don't forget that the last boundary is also followed by two dashes:

```
--some-boundary-string--
```

Hope this helps someone, someday, somewhere. And I hope that person is not trying to send spam. And if they are, I hope the Amazon gods smite them harshly.